# How do I connect to an Oracle database from c# without msdtc

Tags: c#, oracle, msdtc

We are building a website for our client to replace their existing one. Part of this work involves connecting to a remote Oracle database. We do not have Oracle, but I have been able to access the database using SQL Anywhere. I am struggling with getting the code, written in C# (VS2012), to connect to the database. I have tried using an ODBC connection with a query string like this:

> Driver={SQL Anywhere
>   17};DatabaseName=p7grad;EngineName=profilerpm;uid=****;pwd=*****;LINKS=tcpip(host=109.231.209.213;serverport=2638)

I use code similar to this to execute the connection:

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))

{
 try
 {
     using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      {

           cmd.CommandText = query;
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           conn.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           conn.Close();
      }
 }


 catch { }
}
```

When conn.Open() is executed I get an error stating that msdtc has not been configured correctly. I set that up, but the next time I tested the code it said I had to also set up msdtc on the database server. The existing website doesn't need msdtc to be set up on the server, so there must be another way to establish a connection. I have also  tried using SQL Anywhere to make a connection, but that throws the same exception. Can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Comment: Need not to close the connection `conn.Close();` using will take care of that

Comment: Do you really have installed SQL Anywhere  odbc on your machine?